# Android - hide LinearLayout when onFocus on EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

```
    <RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/f1">
        <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/f1textA"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
        <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/f1textB"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/f2">
        ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

How to hide f2 LinearLayout when onFocus at f1textA, and set the f1 to full screen.  When lostFocus on f1textA, show the f2, and f1 remain to original height. (for hide/show customize keyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
 f1textA.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                if(hasFocus){
                //Hide f2 linear layout and show f1 linear layout

                } else{
               //show f1 linear layout and show f2 linear layout
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: How to set the f1 (height) to occupy the space from f2 after hide it ?

Comment: take the parent layout as vertical linear layout and put f1 and f2 linear layout in it.